# Link error in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors

I created a new `C++ project` named *test2* in Visual Studio 2015 this way:

*File > new > project > win32project (test2) > OK > Nest > checking the Empty project > Finish > Add New Item > C++ (source file) "test2" > Add.*

Then I wrote the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int& b = a;
    b++;

    cout << a << ' ' << b << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When running the code I got this serious error:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) test2   c:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\test2\test2\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj)  1*

What is the problem please?

Comment: You have chosen the wrong project type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Do you mean I should choose "Win32 Console Application" instead of "Win32 Project"?

Comment: Yes. That's what's wrong in your case.

Comment: Thank you. Should I now delete my question and let it remain?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with duplicates.